# Neo4j Desktop, Database failed to start

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

During the installation, there's a problem with the connection to the database. After, when I'm in Neo4j desktop there's this problem:

> Conflicts occurred
>
> Database xxx can not be started due to conflicts with external processes.
> To fix this problem, let us change these port configurations:
>
> bolt: 7687 → 11005
> http: 7474 → 11006

But also changing the port it doesn't run.

EDIT: The specific error is:

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security
> constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not
> available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development
> console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons
> include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL
> or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure
> your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is
> configured to use. WebSocket readyState is: 3

Answer (score 2):

Its because the last running instance of neo4j database was not shutdown properly.
Close Neo4J Desktop
On windows, open task manager and look for a process named "Zulu Platform x64 Architecture" and kill it. Now re-attempt opening the db.
On Linux - You would need to find out what the process is called (assuming that problem occurs there)

Comment: This solution works only some times. Other times, I do not see any "Zulu" service. I'm on a Windows machine. Do you have any other pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I noticed that my database did indeed start... I just refreshed neo4j desktop(Reload in the Developer tab or just ctrl+R) and voilà! It's solved
Hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager, and check if there is  a service called Apache Common Daemon?

If yes, you may need to turn it off by going to the [bin directory](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/), open PowerShell, and then try this:

```
Import-Module Neo4j-Management.psd1
Invoke-Neo4j status
```

If it says Neo4j is running even though you don't run anything, you will want to turn it off by using

```
Invoke-Neo4j stop
```

I do not guarantee that this will work. See more: [Windows installation - Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/)